# Hasse Diagram of Poset

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The values I were given are {1,3,4,5,6},{1,2,4,5,6},{1,2,3,6},{1,2,3},{1,5,6},{1,3,6},{1,2},{1,6},{3,5},{1},{3},{4}.

For the Hasse diagram, would {1,2,4,5,6} cover {1,5,6} even though there is a difference of two values, i.e. 4 and 2 are both missing? There doesn't seem to be a  set closer to {1,2,4,5,6} than {1,5,6}.

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty to embed the image in the question post.